# Database Connections in Heroku

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, web-applications

I'm currently working on a small web application that is being hosted on Heroku. I just managed to set up my database and ran a few tests, after which, on Heroku, it shows that I have 5/20 connections used for my database allowance. What exactly does this mean? How can I "eliminate" some of these connections? Thanks!

Comment: A little more info would be helpful - 1) what's the tech stack you are using? Rails, Django, Java? 2) How many dynos have you started? Etc.

Comment: Hi! I'm currently using python with a flask framework. I've only started one dyno.

Comment: If you are using `sqlalchemy` as the database engine, note that it automatically creates a connection pool, which may consume additional connections up to the max configured for the pool (which I believe is 5). For example, you can inspect the status of the connection pool via the `your_engine.pool.status()`. You'll see output like "Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 2  Current Overflow: -3  Checkout out connections: 0".

Comment: Okay, so what exactly does a "connection" suggest? Is it suggesting a client to database connection?